# Marshaling C++ struct with fixed size array into C#

Tags: c#, arrays, mono, marshalling, fixed-width

I have a C# struct declared like so:

```
public struct AdvertisementData {
    public byte SomeId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray , SizeConst = 12)]
    public byte[] AnArray;
  }
```

And it's C++ counterpart:

```
struct AdvertisementData {
  uint8_t SomeId;
  uint8_t AnArray[12];
};
```

When I try to send a reference to a stack-allocated instance of the above struct from C++ to C#, I get: "Structure field of type Byte[] can't be marshalled as LPArray."
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: could you try using `SafeArray`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to marshal it as ByValArray:

```
 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 12)]
  public byte[] AnArray;
```

And also, are you sure that you do not need to set any [LayoutKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your struct?

Comment: The mono interop docs say that structs are layout sequential by default, which is why I think I should be fine.http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries

Comment: Ok, understood. So have you tried to marshal it ByVal?