# Marshalling C struct with fixed size array into C#

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling, fixed-width

Im trying to Marshall a C struct into C# like so

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Shader
{
    public uint id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Raylib.MAX_SHADER_LOCATIONS)]
    public int[] locs;
}
```

And its C counterpart:

```c
typedef struct Shader {
    unsigned int id;                // Shader program id
    int locs[MAX_SHADER_LOCATIONS]; // Shader locations array
} Shader;
```

MAX_SHADER_LOCATIONS is a constant set to 32 in both C and C#.

This solution here is the same as this [Marshaling C++ struct with fixed size array into C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538837/marshaling-c-struct-with-fixed-size-array-into-c-sharp).

The function I am using to test it is

```
[DllImport(nativeLibName,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Shader LoadShader(string vsFileName, string fsFileName);
```

And its C counterpart:

```
Shader LoadShader(const char *vsFileName, const char *fsFileName)
```

When I try to use this function I get the error "Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I checked and it returns a Shader struct not a pointer. I added the C version to the question.

Comment: The return type is the problem.  It is not a "blittable" struct because of the array, that requires the pinvoke marshaller to create the managed struct, copy the data and destroy the C struct.  The latter is the problem, it doesn't know how to do that.  If you can change the C function then give it an extra argument, `Shader*`.  Pretty important that you do, this function always needs *some* way to indicate failure.  Give it an int return value for an error code.  Only other thing you can do is use a fixed-size buffer instead of the array, `public fixed locs int[32];`

Comment: I used fixed before but it requires that I compile as unsafe. So there isn't a way to Marshall a fixed array like that then? I can't really change the signature of the C function as it is part of a library.